# Non stopping recursive CTE, always same result

Tags: common-table-expression, recursive-query

Hello I'm trying to create a recursive cte, but I'm getting always the same line repeating forever.

My scenario is an entity that can be a parent or a child of other entity and I want to get the full hierarchy

My tables are (for simplicity) :

**Entity**
ID | Name

**EntityRelation**
Id | ParentEntityId | ChildEntityId

```
;WITH cte_parent as (

select  
parent.id parentId, 
parent.NAME parentname, 
cast(0 as bigint) childid, 
cast('' as nvarchar(500)) childname
from ENTITY parent
where parent.id not in (
select rel2.CHILDENTITYID  from ENTITYRELATION rel2
)
and parent.id in (select rel3.PARENTENTITYID  from ENTITYRELATION rel3)
and parent.id = 159788
-- This only gets entities with no parent, the top ones
 
UNION ALL

 select  
parent2.id parentId, 
parent2.DISPLAYNAME 
parentname,child2.id childid, 
child2.DISPLAYNAME childname
from ENTITY parent2
join  ENTITYRELATIONSHIP rel4
on rel4.PARENTENTITYID = parent2.ID
join ENTITY child2
on child2.id = rel4.CHILDENTITYID

join cte_parent o
on o.parentid = parent2.id
where parent2.id = 159788

)

select * from cte_parent
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

I've put the parentid = 159788, to get the full hierarchy of just 1 specific top parent, just for testing with smaller data.

This parent only has 1 child, but it keeps repeating forever the same data:

[image]

I was hoping on only getting the top 2 lines.